# how can i filter (where clause) by an aggregate field in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
 Select Distinct Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
 from Metrics m
 group by Product
```

and I want to change the query to only return where TotalDeals = 0.

What is the best way to have this where clause in the query (instead of filtering out of the result set after the fact)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select Product, TotalDeals
FROM
(
 Select Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
 from Metrics m
 group by Product
)
Where TotalDeals=0
```

You don't need distinct as the records are grouped by product

Or

```
Select Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
from Metrics m
group by Product
having sum(Deals) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HAVING`:

```
Select Distinct Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals 
from Metrics m 
group by Product 
HAVING sum(Deals) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` is the clause to filter aggregated fields

```
   ...
   group by Product
   HAVING sum(Deals) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Select Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
     from Metrics m
     group by Product
    having sum(Deals)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work in a MySQL database, and not receive an Error Code 1248: Every derived table must have it own alias,

This query:

```
Select Product, TotalDeals
FROM
(
 Select Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
 from Metrics m
 group by Product
)
Where TotalDeals=0
```

Must be updated to include an **AS** *aliasname* after the close parenthesis, as shown below:

```
Select Product, TotalDeals
FROM
(
 Select Product, sum(Deals) as TotalDeals
 from Metrics m
 group by Product
) AS t1
Where TotalDeals=0
```